# "Prospekt" als Synonym für Aussicht

Tags: translation, etymology, usage, meaning-in-context, synonym

Es geht in dieser Frage um eine bestimmte Benutzung des Wortes "Prospekt" und ob diese so gebräuchlich ist. Es handelt  sich dabei um einen Satz, dessen Richtigkeit ich sofort nach dem Schreiben anzweifelte, er lautet:

> Mit dem Verlust des [...] Jobs ist das Prospekt eines Apartments wohl erstmal vom Tisch.

Das Duden lässt einen solchen Gebrauch offensichtlich nicht gelten, das lateinische Ursprungswort scheint aber genau diese Bedeutung zu haben.

Edit: Jetzt, da ich diese Frage fertig formuliert habe, fällt mir auch ein, woher ich diese Idee bekam, nämlich von der Englischen Gebrauchsweise des Wortes "prospect". Es würde mich allerdings interessieren, ob man das Wort nicht trotzdem  auf diese Weise gebrauchen könnte, oder ob es da eine ähnliche, weniger bekannte Alternative gibt, da ich es für eine schöne Formulierung und auch einigermaßen verständlich halte.

Comment: Sorry, für mich ist ein Prospekt ein kleiner bunter Katalog, sonst nichts. Ramschpost. Werbung. Müll.

Comment: Naja, es gibt schon noch andere Bedeutungen in der Malerei, Theater oder Musik (Orgelbau), und auch in der Wirtschaft (Unterlagen zu zecihnungsfähigen Wertpapieren).

Comment: Das hört sich äußerst antiquiert und gekünstelt an. Im übrigen "der Prospekt", nur im Österreichischen "das Prospekt". Man würde sagen: ist die Aussicht auf ein Apartement erstmal vom Tisch.

Comment: @rogermue Ist mir klar dass man das so nicht sagt, deswegen ja die Frage. "Der Prospekt" also... Da hab ichs doch tatsächlich mein ganzes Leben falsch gesagt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Die Bedeutung, die du hier anwendest und aus dem Englischen kennst, kommt aus dem Lateinischen.

Diese Verwendung ist im Deutschen aber veraltet, genauso wie die allgemeine Bedeutung von *Ansicht, Ausblick*.

Aus dem [Grimmschen Wörterbuch](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GP07924#XGP07924):

> PROSPECT, prospekt, m., mit engl. prospect aus lat. prospectus, aussicht, fernsicht Ludwig 1430: der feind, so wegen nidergelegten thurnsz und thoren .. den freien prospect bisz uff den marktplatz gehabt. S. Bürster 61 (vom j. 1634);
>
> […]
>
> **übertragen auf zukünftiges:
>
> das ehbett im prospekt macht kluge mädchen spröde.**

Die Hervorhebung von mir zeigt die Bedeutung, die du anwendest.

Der Vollständigkeit halber hier auch der Link zum [DWDS](http://dwds.de/?qu=prospekt):

> Zugrunde liegt in beiden Fällen lat. prōspectus ‘Fernsicht, Aussicht, Anblick’, zu lat. prōspicere (prōspectum) ‘aus der Ferne herabschauen, herausschauen, in die Ferne schauen, nach allen Seiten sich umsehen, vor sich erblicken, Aussicht auf etw. haben’; vgl. lat. specere ‘schauen, sehen’.

Comment: Ich würde sogar soweit gehen, es mittlerweile als _false friend_ zu sehen, da es im Englischen diese Bedeutung ja weiterhin hat.

Comment: Danke für die aufschlussreiche Antwort.